# Bootstrap typeahead tab to complete

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I've having a couple issues with a standard bootstrap typeahead element that has an attached onchange event like so:

```
<input id="element1" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  var $element1 = $j("#element1");
  var $output = $j("#output");

  $element1.typeahead({
    "source": ["apple", "airplane", "astronaut", "balloon", "banana"],
    "items": 25
  });

  $element1.on("change", function() {
    console.log("onchange fired");
  });
</script>
```

Issues:

1) If you start typing in a value and press tab the typeahead is autocompleted but the user is not moved to the next input field.  I think this behavior is wrong.  Tabbing should bring the user to the next field.  However, maybe there's a good reason for why it behaves this way?  Does anyone know?

2) If I attach a jquery onchange event then it will get fired twice in firefox (but not chrome or IE).  Why is this happening?  You can follow the steps in the next paragraph and test with this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e4zDx/4/

Begin typing "a" into the first input field and press tab.  The field is autocompleted, the onchange event is fired and the cursor sadly remains in the input field (which was issue 1).  Pressing tab again will move the cursor to the next field, at this point firefox (not chrome or IE) will fire the onchange event again as demonstrated by my output div in the jsfiddle.

I know I can capture the current value within the onchange event and store it on an attribute of the element such as data-oldvalue and only execute the onchange if the current value is different from the old value.  However, what I really want to know is why firefox is triggering the onchange event twice while chrome and ie are not.

I have Windows 7 and the browser versions I'm using are:
Firefox 18.0
Chrome 23.0.1271.97 m
IE 8 (Browser mode IE8, Document Mode IE8 Standards)

Answer (score 0):

Issue 1 : I don't think its a issue because on first tab it autocomplete the Typeahead and on second tab cursor goes to next field because in case if you want to change your selection then you are still on same field to make any changes , Like in my case I triggered an ajax request on Typeahead complete and updated some field in my form , if user wish to change selection then user can delete previous selection and try some new value, so i think it makes to put cursor on same field.

Issue 2: I tried you Js fiddle on Chrome 24.0.1 and firefox 16.0.1 and its firing only 1 event in both cases , may be your firefox version have some issue .